# Glide doesn't want to load images with correct size

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, android-glide

I try to load a big images (671kb and 1.17Mb) with glide (`Util.loadImage` just contains some general Glide methods):

```
private void invalidateImage() {
if (mImage != null) {
  Util.loadImage(mHolder.root.getContext(), mImage)
      .asBitmap()
      .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, final GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
          setImageSource(ImageSource.bitmap(resource));
        }
      });
}
```

}

But `Bitmap resource` depends by device. If i run app in cool device like Samsung SM-N900, resource is OK, resource is a desired bitmap with correct values of width and height:

[image]

If I run app in weak device like Senseit E400, `Bitmap resource` changes his scale to incorrect values:

[image]

I can't understand, what prevents Glide to load image correct. Any ideas?

Comment: don't post code as images

Comment: why not? because it's makes google search difficult?

Comment: because if someone wants to try your piece of code, they can't as they have to type all your code and I don't think anybody have time to do that

Comment: you right, I had not thought about it